# Accessing Music on Mobile Devices

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

Would like to develop an application that utilizes a mobile devices music library. Fairly new to mobile development (have a web programming background) and was looking for any help on how to go about accessing this.

Essentially, i'd like to grab a random song from the library (Itunes, whatever) and have it play for a set amount of time. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into either the iOS or android SDK?  The media API is what is used for android devices I believe http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html